# Getting Entity Model dynamically based on TableName?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-assembly, system.reflection

I am passing a table name to a function and I need to get the name of the entity dynamically and use that entity as normal.

Normal hard coded way 
MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();

i tried to get it but this doesnt work

```
 // Get the Assembly here as the entites exist in another project within the solution

  //Now that we have the assembly, search through it to get the correct entity based on the tablename string
 var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(x => x.FullName.Contains("NAMESPACE")).FirstOrDefault();

                 var type = assembly.GetTypes()
                    .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == tableName);

                    if (type != null)
                    {
                        System.Data.Entity.DbSet myDbSet = context.Set(type);

                       myDbSet myEntity = new ??? <-- I need to create an instance of the entity here

                      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `Activator.CreateInstance` or `DbSet.Create()` to create entity. Then use `DbSet.Add()` to add it to dbset.

See sample below

```
object entityObj = dbSet.Create();

//Populate values using reflection / dynamic
//....

dbSet.Add(entityObj);
dbSet.SaveChanges();
```

Hope this helps.